# Ежечасный перезапуск приложения на python

Tags: python

Я написал панель управления чат-ботами, которую мне надо перезапускать ежечасно, так как после нескольких часов работы чат-боты отключаются от серверов телеграма и их надо вручную перезапускать, а перезапускать через бесконечный цикл в коде чат-ботов не получается, так как он тоже через какое-то время заканчивает свою работу

Comment: Боты не отключаются от серверов телеграма сами по себе

Comment: Можно воспользоваться планировщиком ОС для запуска бота по расписанию, - это просто, но не помню чтобы в планировщике поддерживалась обратная связь. Возможно стоит детально ознакомиться с тем, почему у Вас отваливается бот и думать над решением исходя из возникающей ошибки, а не бороться с последствиями.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin если автор вопроса использует поллинг, да еще код из туториала, то боты вполне себе отключаются от сервера при потере связи.

Comment: @strawdog даже при поллинге он бесконечно реконекнутся пробует, вроде как, по крайней мере на 3 аиограме

Comment: @ClarkDevlin на асинхронных - возможно. а на ванильном телеботе - отваливаются за милую душу. тихонечко падают себе.